# Excel VBA - Allowing for repeating group nodes in XML?

Tags: xml, vba, excel

---

### **Introduction:**

---

Hello everyone,

I looked into every VBA XML topic on StackOverflow to no avail. Apologies as this request is quite a chunk but I attempted to ease the flow as much as possible.

I need to have an Excel to XML converter with dynamically generated template/layout to import into a website. Meaning that I cannot use the integrated Excel to XML as I would have to provide a template and I need the script to be able to generate depending on a user's intent.

For that, I am using a modified version of the Excel to XML script from Raymond Pang over CodeProject (2004).

The script uses "/" delimiters to define the depth and path of the nodes.

---

### **The Problem:**

---

The issue I have at the moment is that I cannot have it to generate repeating groups (that is multiple child nodes group of the same name). Specifically, the way the website works is that I need to have multiple Sections/Section groups.

---

### **Example:**

---

Here's an example Row with Repeating Group Nodes to generate in XML :
[image: Example Row to Generate in XML with Repeating Group Nodes]

The script currently generates it like that:
[image: Wrong as it is only one group named Section]

While I need it to generate like that:
[image: Right as I have two Section groups]

**If what I mean is unclear kindly let me know and I'll try to elaborate.**

---

### **The Script:**

---

Now here's the script used to generate the XML aboves from the "*/suite/sections/section/sections/section/sections/section/name*" header.

```vb
Function GenerateXMLDOM(rngData As Range, rootNodeName As String)

With Worksheets("DATA")
Const NODE_DELIMITER As String = "/"   ' the default node delimiter
Dim intColCount As Integer
Dim intRowCount As Integer
Dim intColCounter As Integer
Dim intRowCounter As Integer
Dim Location As String

Location = "A1:C1"

Dim rngCell As Range
Dim rngCell2 As Range

' Create the XML DOM object
Set ObjXMLDoc = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
ObjXMLDoc.async = False


' NODE_PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION(7) --- reference http://www.devguru.com/Technologies/xmldom/quickref/obj_node.html
Set Heading = ObjXMLDoc.createNode(7, "xml", "")
ObjXMLDoc.appendchild (Heading)

' Set the root node
Set top_node = ObjXMLDoc.createNode(1, rootNodeName, "")
ObjXMLDoc.appendchild (top_node)



Dim Nodes() As String       'Array storing the current splited node names
Dim NodeStack() As String   'Array storing the last node names

Dim new_nodes()
ReDim NodeStack(0)
ReDim new_nodes(0)


 With rngData  ' The selected region on the DATA Excel Sheet passed in

    '   Discover dimensions of the data it will be dealing with...
    intColCount = .Columns.Count
    intRowCount = .Rows.Count

    Dim strColNames() As String     ' The Array of column names
    ReDim strColNames(intColCount)



    ' First Row is the Field/Tag names
    ' Extract all the field names into array "strColNames"
    If intRowCount >= 1 Then
        '   Loop accross columns... and put names in array
        For intColCounter = 1 To intColCount

            '   Mark the cell under current scrutiny by setting
            '   an object variable...
            Set rngCell = .Cells(1, intColCounter)

            '  not support merged cells .. so quit
            If Not rngCell.MergeArea.Address = _
                                        rngCell.Address Then
                  MsgBox ("!! Cell Merged ... Invalid format")
                  Exit Function
            End If

            strColNames(intColCounter) = rngCell.Text

        Next
    End If

    '   Loop down the table's rows
    For intRowCounter = 2 To intRowCount

        ReDim new_nodes(0)
        ReDim NodeStack(0)
        '   Loop accross columns...
        For intColCounter = 1 To intColCount

            '   Mark the cell under current scrutiny by setting
            '   an object variable...
            Set rngCell = .Cells(intRowCounter, intColCounter)


            '   Is the cell merged?..
            If Not rngCell.MergeArea.Address = _
                                        rngCell.Address Then

                  MsgBox ("!! Cell Merged ... Invalid format")
                  Exit Function


            End If

            ' divide the field name by the delimiter to get appropriate node names
            Nodes = Split(strColNames(intColCounter), NODE_DELIMITER)

            If UBound(Nodes) = 0 Then
              ReDim Nodes(1)
              Nodes(1) = strColNames(intColCounter)
            End If

             ' don't count it when no content
             If Trim(rngCell.Text) <> "" Then

                Dim i As Integer
                MatchAll = True
                For i = 1 To UBound(Nodes)

                    If i <= UBound(NodeStack) Then

                        If Trim(Nodes(i)) <> Trim(NodeStack(i)) Then
                            'not match
                            MatchAll = False
                            Exit For

                        End If
                    Else
                      MatchAll = False
                      Exit For
                    End If


                  Next

                  ' match all means in same level as previous, so it needs to output for the last node
                  If MatchAll Then
                      i = i - 0
                  End If


                  If UBound(new_nodes) < UBound(Nodes) Then
                         ' enlong the array
                         ReDim Preserve new_nodes(UBound(Nodes))


                  End If

                  For t = i To UBound(Nodes)
                      ' create uncommon nodes with the previous one
                      Set new_nodes(t) = ObjXMLDoc.createNode(1, Nodes(t), "")

                  Next


                  For t = i - 1 To UBound(Nodes) - 1

                      If t >= 1 Then
                          ' connect the nodes based on the hierarchy
                          new_nodes(t).appendchild (new_nodes(t + 1))
                      End If

                  Next
                  Set Textcont = ObjXMLDoc.createTextNode(Trim(rngCell.Text))
                  new_nodes(UBound(Nodes)).appendchild (Textcont)

                  If i = 1 Then
                      top_node.appendchild (new_nodes(1))
                  End If


                  NodeStack = Nodes



              End If

        Next ' finished a column
    Next
End With


'   Return the XMLDOM
 Set GenerateXMLDOM = ObjXMLDoc

End With
End Function
```

---

### **Troubleshooting:**

---

I believe the issue resides within the fact that I add the child notes and instantly go back to the root .

*Node (t)* is always *"/Suite/"*
[image]

I believe a solution would be to give a way to the script to remember the parent node  and consider that any  after that are groups within themselves.

Other than the fact I failed to code this in, I also can't have ALL instances of Sections/Section to create groups as I may have something like *Sections/Section/Sections/Section/Sections/Section/Sections/Section/Name* depending on the depth of layer the data needs to be.
Perhaps by having something check the name of the directory and if the header ends in "/Section" it creates a group and if there is something else after "/Section" it continues down the path? Any other way to do this?

A tremendous amount of thanks for any help, hints and attempt at fixing this.

---

### **Requested Data:**

---

**Edit: There are too many modules and a Startform intertwined together to get this to work efficiently piece by piece.
I have thus uploaded the file in question on my Google Drive, it will be much easier for you to check it out.**

Apologies if this isn't allowed, I did look around and didn't find anything against it. But I realized there is no way I can efficiently share the project otherwise unless I do a major hack into it to simplify it and it might void results.

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4nBtjoQSKsSSVRhVEp6dklDYlU

This is an example of header another script will generate from user-inputted Data. This is usually in the very first row of the DATA sheet, the cells below each of these lines contain the information (name, description etc.) you can input anything in these. I haven't found a way to paste these successfully, apologies for that.

These are two sets of the same path as demonstrated in the screenshots above, I need the second set to be separated from the first at the previous /sections/ node.

```
/suite/sections/section/sections/section/name   /suite/sections/section/sections/section/description    /suite/sections/section/sections/section/sections/section/name  /suite/sections/section/sections/section/name   /suite/sections/section/sections/section/description    /suite/sections/section/sections/section/sections/section/name
```

Comment: Can you post a few rows of input data in *DATA* worksheet? And not as screenshot. That way, we can grab the data with your code to run on our end (i.e., [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: @Parfait Most definitely! I added the Data in a new "Requested Data:" section as well as all the other codes so you can have a working version :) Thanks a lot for looking into this!
There is also a FileBrowser and Startform to trigger the script, would you need these also?

Comment: @Parfait I settled to share the file itself instead as there are too functions and subs that needs each other to get this to work without. Let me know if this is an issue but I don't think I can find another way to efficiently share the project.

Comment: How did you get an Excel file like that? It seems to have derived from an XML source.

Comment: It is from a website named CodeProject. I'll need to modify it heavily to fit my need but I need to be able to crack that problem first, else I can't go on with what I have to do.

Comment: So it is an XML source? Consider XSLT then that transforms XML from one form to another. Excel VBA can run XSLT. Post the source XML.